# Url rewriting using .htaccess file on php

Tags: php, html, .htaccess

i am using htaccess for dynamic url rewriting. i want to show the test.php as test.html

the htaccess code is

```
Options +FollowSymlinks

RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.html$ $1.php [nc]
```

after running test.php, the browser show test.php on address bar. but if i change test.php as test.html  the page give the same content. my apache config file are fine. how can i solve this?
thanks to help me..

Comment: Sorry, we'd all expect that the behaviour you describe is what you intended you do... If not you will have to edit your question to make clear what is actually is you want to do.

Answer (score 1):

You cant deny access to your .php

Yon need to put in your a tag the html link and it will go to php in the background.

If you still want to sow only the html address you can put regex in your php file and check if the extension is php. if so redirect the page to html.

example:

```
<?php 
     $temp = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
     $temp = explode('.', $temp);
     if($temp[count($temp)-1] == "php"){
         header("Location: test.html", true, 301);
     }
?>
```

*** not tasted !!! ***

Comment: I think it would be a bit salty.